# I want to switch to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

Ok, I work for a managed services provider. We manage 30 organizations, all who run Windows networks. I run a highly complex Windows network at home. I use a lot of bleeding edge Windows stuff.

Years ago, I began working with Linux as side projects. Now I am fairy proficient, mostly in web hosting server tech.

I would like to switch to Linux as my driving OS for my personal laptop, which I use both at work and at my home office (Windows). The tools I use for work are Win-only. I use the Office suite 24/7. I use the Adobe suite 24/7.

How can I switch? No need to mention GIMP, LibreOffice, and Office365 in-browser... while those do work, I am a power user and those are not power tools, but only "suitable replacements".

Should I keep my machine Win10 and run Linux as a VM? I feel like I would always default back to Win though. Should I run Linux and VM Windows? I feel like my laptop would lose a lot of functionality that I now have, such as DirectAccess synchronization over the WAN.

Should I dual boot and run Windows at work? Should I keep my personal laptop Linux and remote into my work desktop running Windows when I am at the office?

I run a ThinkPad Carbon X1 Gen 5, 16GB RAM, i7 7700, 500GB SSD NVMe, so even a VM option performance will not be an issue.

Comment: The whole point of an operating system is to run applications. It seems weird to me that you “would like to switch to Linux as [your] driving OS” when “the tools [you] use for work are Win[dows]-only” — if you want to use Windows applications (or mostly Windows applications), use Windows. It would help if you could clarify why you want to switch to Linux; and if you are serious about it, you will have to switch applications too. (There’s no reason you can’t be a power user on Linux applications, you’d need to relearn things, that’s “all”.)

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah what you say makes sense! Professionally and in a home lab setting, I work with Windows. But I also do a lot of Linux, mostly virtualizedinstances of web host. I am also big into dabbling in open source platforms which happen to run mainly on Linux (chat applications, web servers, torrenting/freenas, file sharing services, sms gateways, CRMs, etc). So I use Linux daily, but not as a daily driver. I feel like if I were to go full Linux, it would significantly sharpen my skill, which would be good for my time spent on Linux and my resume both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use Windows exclusively and work and home, I would leave Windows 10 on your laptop and use Linux in a VM.

My work environment is a mix of Windows and Linux. All of our desktops and laptops are a mix of Windows 7 and 10, but 90% of our server infrastructure is Linux (Suse Linux Enterprise Server). My work desktop in Windows 10, but I have a Linux VM on it. I find that I can do almost everything I need to do in Windows, including managing our Linux servers. But there are rare occasions that a tool I need runs better or is exclusive to Linux so I fire up my VM and do what I need to do, all without having to reboot Windows to boot into Linux.

Of course this is just my opinion. You could try all your options and see which works best for you and your environment.

Comment: Thanks @Luke Strohm that is a good idea. I am mainly interested in Kali Linux and getting into pen testing to enhance the security side of my resume. Also interested in managing multiple SSH connections to one of a dozen servers I manage via terminal instead of via an app in Windows (which works just fine, just feels lame).